# htaccess mod_rewrite redirect to subfolder, that maintains paths to files inside parent folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to change the starting page of a website from `www.example.com/index.php` to `www.example.com/shows/index.php`.

since both files are named `index`, i figured a directory redirect should do the trick.

I was going to use the following code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^$ shows [L]
```

The one caveat is that the `www.example.com/index.php` page is linked to, elsewhere in the site, and I want to ensure those links will still work.

So my question is: **Is there a way of triggering the rewrite *only* if the directory is called, and *not* if files inside the directory are called? Oh, and is my logic that this will work to solve my problem correct? Or do you have a better suggestion?**

Comment: Can you give me an example of what you mean, I want to make sure I understand correctly, thanks

Comment: @Book Of Zeus - I actually tested this out, and it's working the way it's suppose to. But one thing it is doing, is showing the `/shows/` at the end of the URL on redirect. Is there as way for it to show only the base URL even though it redirects to a sub-folder?

Comment: I'm sorry, you will have to give me an example, I tried your code and it work on my side.

Comment: @Book Of Zeus - Well the redirect is working fine. A browser pointed towards http://www.example.com/ is redirected to http://www.example.com/shows/. But I'm wondering how to have the browser still show only http://www.example.com/ after the redirect. Is that possible?

Comment: using your rule example.com redirects to www.examples.com (that works) then you redirect everything to /shows/. So you want example.com to go to examples.com and www.example.com to www.example.com/shows/?

Comment: @Book Of Zeus - I'm sorry. My fault. Lets forget about the first redirect. That was there by mistake. So the redirect should only be `RewriteRule ^$ shows [L]`. As I said, it's doing what it should, but I'm curious if there is a way, that even though the page has been redirected to `www.example.com/shows/`, the browser shows `www.examples.com`? So essentially the user has no idea that there has been a redirect?

Comment: No problem, either you put /shows/ or not, it will go the the same place so the user has no idea that example.com goes to example.com/shows/.

Comment: @Book Of Zeus - Ok, just to make sure, this is the code I am using: `Options +FollowSymlinks   RewriteEngine On   RewriteRule ^$ shows [L]`. With that code, should it not show that the redirection has happened? Because right now it is showing `www.example.com/shows/` as the URL. Is my code right? Am I missing something? Because I always thought mod_rewrite would not show the redirect, while just plain redirect would. Am I wrong?

Comment: Do you have other rules in your .htaccess or vhost? because I am showing an "L" redirect and not an "R" redirect, when I use www.example.com. It does not go to: www.example.com/shows/

Comment: @Book Of Zeus - I don't have other rules. What do you mean by, "...I am showing an "L" redirect and not an "R" redirect..."? I ended up finding out what the problem was. The code I was using was `RewriteEngine On RewriteRule ^$ shows [L]` when it should have been `RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ shows/ [L]`. All I was missing was the forward slash following `shows`. Sorry for wasting your time. But I am still curious what you meant by your last comment. Should I be using `[R]` instead of `[L]`? I'm not completely sure what they mean as of yet...

Comment: Oh that make sense, nice. R = real redirect, it check the headers of the page whereas, L = it's like an alias. (install httpfox and you will see the difference) good finding!

Comment: @Book Of Zeus - K so I thought that was the solution. Ends up that all night long, any of the links to files in the home directory were not linking! So while yes, adding the slash made the URL only show the domain name and not the redirected folder, it also made the redirected folder the home folder, and messed up the links. Again, I don't know if I'm missing something, or maybe it's just not possible to do what I wish to do. Are you following? Do you think the fact that I'm using `L` instead of `R` might make a difference?

Comment: Yes: R will remove "duplicate" content since everything from domain.com will redirect to www.domain.com, L creates the symlink (good for SEO) from your www.domain.com